# Can't pull data base from heroku for my Django app

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to use the command:

```
PGUSER=postgres PGPASSWORD=postgres heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL localDB --app  django-www-app345
```

To pull by postgres DB from my heroku app. But it gives me the error:

```
!    createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
 !    
 !    Unable to create new local database. Ensure your local Postgres is working and try again.
```

I don't have a template1 DB nor do I have localDB, my postgres user is postgres and so is my password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your `pga_hba.conf` file and search for this line:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
local  all      all          peer
```

and change `peer` for `md5`:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
local  all      all          md5
```